# how much helium would you need to pick up one kilogram on mars

Tags: gravity

how much helium would you need to pick up one kilogram on mars? is there an equaison that can be used? 
thnx alot!

Comment: The proposed duplicate shows how one would calculate the lift of a helium balloon on Earth, it should be simple enough to swap out $g_{Earth}$ for $g_{Mars}$ and determine the volume of the balloon necessary.

Comment: @KyleKanos No, you need to know the atmospheric density on Mars as well.  You need to have a large enough volume of helium at the atmospheric pressure on Mars to produce lift.  The question is ill-formed in any case, since it depends on the pressure of the helium volume itself.  To emphasize: no amount of helium will lift a gram on the moon, since there's no atmospheric pressure there at all.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: True, you do need to know $\rho_{Mars}$, fortunately [NASA can help you with that](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/atmosmrm.html).